# I want to write a snippet for console.log() with some additions in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

How to do a snippet, that copy selected variable from a code and print it on a next empty line and if there is no empty line below, it should just move code 1 line down and print.
Does it make sense?

Example:

```
**btnOpenModal**[i].addEventListener('click', () => {}); 
->>>*shortcut*

btnOpenModal[i].addEventListener('click', () => {}); 
console.log(btnOpenModal);
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: This is easy to do if it is okay to insert the `console.log.....` line below (after inserting an empty line there) even if that line below was already empty.  Otherwise it is a lot more work for little gain.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my partial solution, I coudn't figure out how to print the text on the next line, but I could use snippet with text in clipboard.

**Snippets file:**

```json
    "advanced-log":
    {
        "prefix": "log",
        "body": "console.log(`${$CLIPBOARD}`)",
        "description": "console log command"
    }
```

**Keybinding file:**

```json
    {
        "key": "cmd +l",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "langId": "javascript",
            "name": "advanced-log"
        }
    }
```